# what does it mean !! (not not) in javascript and when to use it

Tags: javascript

i try to reading code of `pandajs` game engine and according to this code from [github](https://github.com/ekelokorpi/panda-engine/blob/master/src/engine/audio.js#L481) :

```
playMusic: function(name, loop) {
    var volume = this.musicMuted ? 0 : this.musicVolume;

    if (typeof loop === 'undefined') loop = true;

    if (this.currentMusic) this._stop(this.currentMusic);

    this.currentMusic = this._play(name, !!loop, volume);
    this.currentMusicName = name;

    return !!this.currentMusic;
}
```

and it's return `!!this.currentMusic` i try to figure it out but i cant understand why he use it. for example this code :

```js
function a(arg){
  console.log(!!arg);
}

a(true)
a(false)
```

if i pass true it's print true and if i pass false it's print false , so why not just return `this.currentMusic` instead of `!!this.currentMusic` or in my example just `console.log(arg)` instead of `console.log(!!arg)`

Comment: Try `a(null)` or `a("foo")` with and without the `!!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it coerces the object to boolean, if it was null, undefined etc it would be false else true

```js
let x = null;
let y = 1;
console.log(!!x);
console.log(!!y);
```